# Why isn't a loop on $S^1$ nullhomotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why I'm wrong. Given a loop that starts on the point $(1,0)$ and does 1 loop in the clockwise direction in $S^1$ cant I construct a homotopy in the following manner: H(x,0) = the original loop
H(x,1) = the point $(1,0)$.
H(x,y) = a loop that starts at $(1,0)$ and then goes $(1-y)\cdot2\pi$ clockwise.

I know this isn't the most formal explanation but why is this wrong? It seems to uphold the definition of a homotopy, but it has to be wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nullhomotopic means homotopic to the constant curve throug a homotopy of closed curves (with endpoint and starting point coinciding). Your $H(x,y)$ does not fulfil this requirement.

Comment: For $y\neq 0,1$, $H(x,y)$ doesn't describe a loop.